# Angular CLI Proxy conf is not working for POST request

Tags: angular, proxy, cors

I am running into an issue when using **proxy.conf** with angular 5. I am trying to hit a https dev server (with invalid certificate) from angular app running on localhost. The proxy I have is working perfectly for GET requests. But for POST requests its failing with the following error

> OPTIONS https://www.dev.xxxx.au/api/carg/v1/enquiry 405 ()
>
> Failed to load https://www.dev.xxxx.au/api/carg/v1/enquiry: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4455' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

I know that OPTIONS is called by browser before POST, but couldn't find a way to make it work.

Following is my proxy conf

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://www.dev.xxxxx.au",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api/carg/v1/enquiry": "https://www.dev.xxxx.au/api/enquiry"
    }
  }
}
```

Tried a lot of combinations but couldn't make it work. Any ideas... ?

Comment: It sounds like your Angular service where you're using the HttpClient is pointed at https://www.dev.carers.healthdirect.org.au/api/carg/v1/enquiry instead of using a relative path: '/api/enquiry'. 

Can you share your angular code?

Comment: Hey @LucasTétreault, thanks for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, I can share the code snippet only on Monday.

Comment: Okie dokie. I'll be waiting 

Comment: Hi @LucasTétreault, Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Like you said I was pointing to the absolute url in HttpClient. I have corrected it and it worked smoothly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @LucasTétreault pointed out, the problem is that HttpClient is pointing to absolute url (my bad).

```
 this.url = environment.CHS_BASE_URL;
 let path = '/api/carg/v1/enquiry';
 this.url = this.url + path;
 return this.httpClient.post<EnquiryResponse>(this.url,request, config);
```

Corrected it as below and it worked smooth

```
//this.url = environment.CHS_BASE_URL;
 let path = '/api/carg/v1/enquiry';
 //this.url = this.url + path;
 return this.httpClient.post<EnquiryResponse>(path,request, config);
```